# uninstall youtube-viewer (ppa)

Tags: uninstall, ppa, youtube

i installed youtube-viewer as per the documentation: https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

now i don't want it, but:

removing it as suggested here does not work: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/12/how-to-remove-ppa-ubuntu `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

it is not listed in software and updates where it might be removed as suggested here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-ppas-installation-removal-security/

is it true that "When installed directly from the source (as opposed to building it as a package and installing it with the package manager), I'm afraid [manually deleting the files] is the best option"? https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer/issues/133

thus: ppa should generally be avoided if it's such a hassle to remove, or this is an unusual case?

Answer (score 3):

If you installed the software via the PPA, you can uninstall it like this:

```
sudo apt remove --purge youtube-viewer
```

The commands you had in your question will remove the repository where the application came from, but not the application itself.

Comment: i was worried about using purge because it sounds aggressive, one of those links says purge will "remove all packages installed from a PPA, downgrade any packages it has affected, and remove the PPA". What if there is some related package, eg youtube-dl, that i want unaffected? cheers

Comment: The `--purge` flag will remove any configuration files you may have for the package. You do not need to use it, though. A simple `sudo apt remove {package}` is also fine.

Comment: strange: i just ran a basic clean "sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove" and now the app is gone, not sure i understand why, it seemed more stubborn to remove yesterday

Comment: @neverdimed to remove PPA with its package you have to use `ppa-purge ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` instead of `add-apt-repository -r ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` .

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for the reply. Info says "ppa-purge will reset all packages from a PPA to the standard
versions released for your distribution." But isnt there a possibility that i dont want this? Eg, maybe some other program i rely on makes use of a related package and it reverts to the 'standard version'? or is this ppa totally isolated and with no impact on anything else

Comment: You are right. It depends on the use-case. webupd8 provides many packages, so purging it will remove all its packages and downgrade part of them to versions for the distribution. There is no universal solution here.